# Sql join in two tables and return empty tab as Unavaliable

Tags: sql, join

In a SQL join, table 1 contains person info with city and table 2 contains city matched to country such as:-

Table #1

```
ID   Name       City
-------------------------
1    Kishan     Pokhara
2    Ram        Delhi
3    Shyam      Beijing
```

Table #2

```
City      Country
----------------------
Pokhara   Nepal
Delhi     India
```

I want to get the person ID, Name, Country so while joining the tables I want these items and if there is no country available for a city, I want "Unavailable" written in the country columns. Thanks

Comment: Please share some working example to understand what you have done so far. It would be best if you try it  first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below using `left join` and use `coalesce()`  function to replace null country as 'Unavailable'

```
select id, name, a.city,coalesce(country,'Unavailable') as country
from table1 a left join table2 b on a.city=b.city
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the coalesce function but now I do.